# Using Bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" and scrollIntoView() to show and scroll to content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On a site I'm building with Bootstrap 3, there is a section that is hidden using the `collapse` class. I have added a button to toggle the section so it can become visible. That all works fine. What I need is the ability to toggle the content AND to scroll to the section when it is shown.

Here is my button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#benefits" data-toggle="collapse">Learn More</button>
```

Here is my content:

```
<section id="benefits" class="text-white collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Text goes here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Finally, here I've attempted to bind things together using jQuery (though my jQuery skills are very limited):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#benefits").bind('shown', function() {
        document.getElementById('benefits').scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

Can anyone spot the problem with my code above, or suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 18):

You should bind to the appropriate event in the Bootstrap collapse plugin: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events

```
$('#benefits').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  this.scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: Reference for the newer BS: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#events

Answer (score 7):

get the element form the event

```
    $(document).on('shown.bs.collapse', function(event){
        //console.log( "in! print e: " +event.type);
        event.target.scrollIntoView();
    });
```

Comment: Good if someone wants to apply it globally on a page and not just a specific element

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to have a nicer animation than this.scrollIntoView() use. Then you can adjust the animationspeed.

```
$('#benefits').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#benefits").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: That's more graceful UX than the scrollIntoView

Comment: MUCH nicer, thanks!